# Error: Correlation failed in Asp.net core MVC with Azure AD authentication

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I created an Asp.Net Core 2 MVC application with Azure AD Authentication. The following unhandled exception is thrown after the authentication is completed and the callback url is called.

The application is hosted in a web farm, this only happens when the app is accessed through the load balancer. If I modify my host file to access one of the servers directly I don't get any error.

> Exception: Correlation failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+d__12.MoveNext()

Comment: This may be a Network issue. What load balancer are you using?

Comment: I'll ask more details to the network team but I know they call it F5, it wouldn't be rare if that's the issue since it's a new one they recently installed and they've had all kind of issues. What should I tell them to look for in the load balancer config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late update. As suggested by Wayne this turned out to be a problem in the load balancer, the solution was to enable cookie persistence which basically warranties that requests from each client always hit the same back-end server

Comment: can you share the solution how did you enabled the enable cookie persistence